# The number of a sliding window for each element in the list of number?

Tags: algorithm, sliding

Let L be a list of numbers as [7,9,0,3,5,2]. When creating a sliding windows of stride 1 and size 3 I have the following windows :

(7,9,0)
(9,0,3)
(0,3,5)
(3,5,2).

My question is if there is a simple formula to give the number of windows for each position in L ?

For example : If we note N the length of L and M the size of the sliding window, we have this formula to get the total number of windows  N-M+1

But I'm looking for another formula like f(i) where i is the position  : f(1)=1, f(2)=2,f(3)=3, f(4)=2,f(5)=1

Comment: So you answer your own question. Is there still a question then? If so, can you provide the expected result for the example you gave?

Comment: No, the formula I give is for the total number of windows. I'm looking for another formula like  f(1)=1, f(2)=2,f(3)=3, f(4)=2,f(5)=1

Comment: I also know that for each position the number of windows in which the position occurs is  between 1 and M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given:

- `n`: the size of the array
- `stride`: divides the starting offset of a slice
- `size`: size of a slice
- `k`: the index for which we want to know the number of slices that include this index.

Then the pseudo code for getting that count in constant time is:

```py
get_count(n, stride, size, k):
    return max(0, 1 + min(k, n - size) / stride - max(0, k - size + stride) / stride);
```

... where integer division is intended. So for example, in JavaScript syntax:

```js
function getCount(n, stride, size, k) {
    return Math.max(0, 1 + Math.floor(Math.min(k, n - size) / stride) 
                         - Math.floor(Math.max(0, k - size + stride) / stride));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have another question : how can I get the position of each original index in the new list. For example in above  :  [7,9,0,3,5,2] and the new one [7,9,0,9,0,3, 0,3,5, 3,5,2]. So 9 is in the position 2 and 3 in the new list

Comment: Hi! If you have a new question, then please consider posting it as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649161/get-the-positions-of-elements-after-a-sliding-window-on-a-list-of-numbers