# Get the positions of elements after a sliding window on a list of numbers

Tags: algorithm, sliding

Let L be a list of numbers as  `[7,9,0,3,5,2]` . When creating a sliding windows of stride 1 and size 3 I have the following windows :

`(7,9,0) (9,0,3) (0,3,5) (3,5,2)` .
Then I applied function on every on window and I get a score of each value on the window.

and I store them in the new Liste :
 `P = [f(1,7),f(1,9),f(1,0),f(2,9),f(2,0),f(2,3), f(3,0),f(3,3),f(3,5), f(4,3),f(4,5),f(4,2)]` where f is a function that take 2 input (a window index and a value).

How can I get the scroes of each element on L  ?

For example,  the number 9 has two scores `f(1,9)` and `f(2,9)`.

The number 0 has three scores : `f(1,0),f(2,0)` and `f(3,0)`.

Comment: *"get the position of each original index"*: do you mean "...of each original **value**"? Is the input a *value* or an *index*? What if the input array has duplicates... does that affect the output you expect?

Comment: I edited the question and hope it's clear to you. Thnaks

Comment: Index `i` will be at position `2` in the `i-2`th triplet, at position `1` in the `i-1` triplet, and at position `0` in the `i`th triplet. So the new indices will be `3*(i-2)+2, 3*(i-1)+1, 3*i`

Comment: What if the input array has duplicates... does that affect the output you expect?

Comment: Yes, the input array may have duplicates.

Comment: So what do you expect for the input (9, 9, 9, 9) and 9?

Comment: f(1, 9),f(1,9),f(1,9), f(2,9),f(2,9) (stride=1, size_wind=3)

Comment: So do you want as output that array P? Or something else? You write *"For example, the number 9 has two scores"*: is there something you expect to get in this respect? Can you be explicit about the output requirements?

Comment: For example I want the average of the scores of each intial value .

Comment: Can you give the expected results for your examples in your question, in the expected output format? The title says you want "positions of elements" and here you write you want "average of scores". This is quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, I want the position to be able te get the differents scroes and then use some aggregation functions.

Comment: ```[f(1,7),(f(1,9)+f(2,9))/2,(f(1,0),f(2,0),f(3,0))/3, (f(2,3)+f(3,3)+f(4,3))/3,(f(3,5)+f(4,5))/2,f(4,2)]```.

Comment: You asked about getting positions, about getting P, about getting averages, about getting number of occurrences... I am confused about what you expect as it seems a moving target. I will leave this for others to look at.

Comment: I understand that it is not very clear. The key to the solution lies in the positions. If I have the positions, I can then do whatever I want with the values. I mentioned averages because you asked me that/

Comment: Could you please give a solution to get the position ?

Comment: I think I did in a previous comment.

Comment: I did not understand your solution. For example how can I get the position of the value 5 in the example above ?

Comment: Value 5 is at index `i=4` in list `[7,9,0,3,5,2]`. Therefore it will be at position 2 in triplet 2, at position 1 in triplet 3 (and it would be at position 0 in triplet 4, except there is not triplet 4 because it's the end of the list). Please note that I counted all indices and positions starting at 0. If you start at 1 instead of 0, then you have to add 1 where appropriate.

Comment: And how Can I do this from the  new List P (no triplet concept).

Comment: Well, a triplet has 3 elements, so "position j in triplet k" becomes "index `3*k+j`" in list P.

Comment: How can I automate this in a function (python for example, always stride =1 ) ?

Comment: Well you need to start by choosing a programming language. And then writing the code that you want, with the appropriate formula when needed.